# What is the best method to trigger a mouse indicator using synthetic events?

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojox.charting

I have some charts with a mouse indicators attached. I want to activate the indicator via events from other places in my app on a certain location in the data.

My basic approach so far has been to change some of the values in another event object, and then pass it to the onMouseMove() method in all of my indicators like so:

```
funct.forEach(registry.byClass("graph"), function (item) {
    on(item, "mouseover", function (e) {
        funct.forEach(registry.byClass("indicator"), function (indicator) {
            var position = domGeom.position(indicator.chart.node, false);
            e.pageX = e.clientX;
            e.pageY = position.y - 10;
            indicator.onMouseMove(e);
        });
    });
});
```

The `onMouseMove()` method is found in the path dojox/charting/action2d/MouseIndicator.js, and looks like looks like:

```
onMouseMove: function(event){
    if(this._isMouseDown || this.opt.mouseOver){
        this._onMouseSingle(event);
    }
},

_onMouseSingle: function(event){
    var plot = this.chart.getPlot(this._uName);
    plot.pageCoord  = {x: event.pageX, y: event.pageY};
    plot.dirty = true;
    this.chart.render();
    eventUtil.stop(event);
},
```

This works, but is a disgusting hack because I don't know what would happen if `e` changed, or if there are side effects that are not being processed by directly calling `onMouseMove()`. Is there a more uniform and correct way to accomplish what I am trying to accomplish?

This is on dojo 1.10

Comment: You could try the `dojo/topic` module (publish and subscribe) for communicating  between objects. As per the documentation `Because topics are not bound to a particular object, they are useful for communication between multiple instances or various different types of objects.`

Comment: So the code fragment above is actually within a `topic.subscribe`, and I am making heavy use of the framework in my app. The issue is that at some point, I have to call the `onMouseMove(event)` with a properly formatted event. I don't like doing so because I am worried about side effects caused by both the event and calling `onMouseMove(event)`, which doesn't seem to be the public interface for the MouseIndicator object.

Comment: can you show what onMouseMove() function looks like?

Comment: Sorry, probably should have been there in the first place. Added to original post in edit.

Comment: I may be out of my depth here. Just a suggestion. What if you clone (using **dojo.clone**) the event object and use the cloned event object as parameter to onMouseMove() call. e.g `on(item, "mouseover", function (e) { var cloneEvtObj = dojo.clone(obj); funct.forEach(.....; cloneEvtObj.pageX = cloneEvtObj.clientX; cloneEvtObj.pageY = position.y - 10; indicator.onMouseMove(cloneEvtObj);` Hope I making some sense over here. The only problem I see that in `_onMouseSingle()` it uses `eventUtil.stop(event);`.